# Highlight an array of nodes in Autodesk Viewer

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer

**Problem:**

I have an array of nodes that I would like to highlight when an action happens.

**My Attempted Solution**

I have tried using code from the model browser, but it seems to only accept one dbId at a time. I have tried to iterate over my array and call it, but the highlighting doesn't work when that is done.

```
for (var i = 0; i < dbIdsArray.length; i++) {
    viewerApp.getCurrentViewer().impl.rolloverObjectNode(dbIdsArray[i]);
}
```

Any advice on how to implement this correctly would be a great help.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to highlight a couple of dbids, there are some different ways depending on your requirement.

- Maybe you can use the API Viewer3D.isolate() to highlight the
  selected objects by isolating them, you can just input dbId array as
  follow, also, you can zoom the selected items to the viewer window
  use the API Viewer3D.fitToView() to focus on them:

  ```
      viewer.isolate(dbIdArray);
      viewer.fitToView(dbIdArray);
  ```
- If you want to highlight the selected objects with different color,
  maybe you can try the new API Viewer3D.setThemingColor(), here is the
  simple code sample. Remember you need to clear the color using
  Viewer3D.clearThemingColors(). The simple code sample should be like:

Comment: I think the first approach using isolate and fitToView should meet our requirements. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I'm able to highlight components using following code:

```
viewer.addEventListener(
      Autodesk.Viewing.SELECTION_CHANGED_EVENT,            
      function (e) {                
        if(e.dbIdArray.length) {                    
            var dbId = e.dbIdArray[0];                    
            viewer.impl.highlightObjectNode(
                viewer.model, dbId, true, false)                                            
            viewer.select([])
            viewer.impl.sceneUpdated(true)
        }           
    })
```

This is using function:

viewer.impl.highlightObjectNode = function(model, dbId, value, simpleHighlight)