# Highlight multiple elements like hover effect in Autodesk Forge

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer

I want to get the highlight effect like when I hover on an element on Forge Viewer. Is there any available function on Forge Viewer to do it on multiple elements at the same time. Thank you [image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As already answered in this post [Highlight an array of nodes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41167920/highlight-an-array-of-nodes-in-autodesk-viewer), you could use `viewer.setThemingColor()` function to highlight elements with the color of your choice.
And `viewer.clearThemingColors()` to remove the highlight.

Comment: Yes, there's no way to apply the actual hover effect to elements yourself but you can set the `setThemingColor` method to apply a custom color (and opacity!) to multiple object IDs.